# modifying User Defined function into a view

Tags: sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions

I inherited a User Defined function I’m trying to modify and having some trouble.  I would like to modify it into a regular query and then make it into a view. The function is  **ufn_B2H_Enrolled_Clients_List.**  This function pulls a list of clients enrolled in program during a time period selected. Within  **ufn_B2H_Enrolled_Clients_List** is a function **ufn_B2H_STATUSES_THROUGH_DT** . This selects the maximum status change a client had during the time range selected  so if a client was enrolled then disenrolled and then enrolled again the function is not function them into the count.

What I would like is to take ufn_B2H_Enrolled_Clients_List and turn it into a regular query/view  with an output that looks like this:

```
Total_Clients_Enrolled     Month    Year 
252                         1      2013
247                         2      2013
303                         3      2013




**ufn_B2H_Enrolled_Clients_List Function**

RETURNS varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
      -- Declare the return variable here
      DECLARE @VALUE varchar(100)
      SELECT  @VALUE = VALUE 
      FROM ENUMS
      WHERE NAME = @NAME AND NUMBER = @NUMBER
      IF @VALUE IS NULL
            SET @VALUE = 'unknown'
      RETURN (@VALUE)
END

GO


CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_B2H_Enrolled_Clients_List](@From_DT datetime, @To_DT datetime)
RETURNS @retB2H_Enrolled_Clients_List TABLE 
(
  CLT_NBR int
  )
AS 
BEGIN 
      INSERT INTO @retB2H_Enrolled_Clients_List
    --Include all clients enrolled prior to the period end date


      SELECT CLT_NBR
      FROM ECMS.dbo.ufn_B2H_STATUSES_THROUGH_DT(@To_DT) s1
      WHERE s1.B2H_STATUS=4 AND s1.Max_Effect_DT <DATEADD(d,1,@To_DT)
            --Exclude all clients disenrolled or transferred out prior to the start date
            EXCEPT
            SELECT s2.CLT_NBR
            FROM ECMS.dbo.ufn_B2H_STATUSES_THROUGH_DT(@To_DT) s2 JOIN ECMS.dbo.ufn_B2H_STATUSES_THROUGH_DT(@To_DT) s1 ON s1.CLT_NBR=s2.CLT_NBR
            WHERE s2.B2H_STATUS IN (7,9) AND s2.Max_Effect_DT <@From_DT AND s2.Max_Effect_DT>s1.Max_Effect_DT AND s1.B2H_STATUS IN (4,8)
                  --Exclude all clients who transferred in after the prior end date.
                  EXCEPT
                  SELECT s3.CLT_NBR
                  FROM ECMS.dbo.B2H_STATUS s3 JOIN ECMS.dbo.ufn_B2H_STATUSES_THROUGH_DT(@To_DT) s1 ON s1.CLT_NBR=s3.CLT_NBR
                  WHERE s3.B2H_STATUS = 8 AND s1.B2H_STATUS IN (4,8) AND s3.EFFECT_DT > @To_DT AND s3.Effect_DT>s1.Max_Effect_DT

RETURN
END

GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_B2H_STATUSES_THROUGH_DT](@Through_DT datetime)
RETURNS @retB2H_STATUSES_THROUGH_DT TABLE 
(
   CLT_NBR int
  ,B2H_STATUS int
  ,Max_EFFECT_DT datetime
  )
AS 
BEGIN 
   INSERT INTO @retB2H_STATUSES_THROUGH_DT
       S


       ELECT CLT_NBR
               ,B2H_STATUS
               ,MAX(EFFECT_DT) AS Max_Effect_DT
            FROM [ECMS].[dbo].[B2H_STATUS]
            WHERE EFFECT_DT<DATEADD(d,1,@Through_DT)
            GROUP BY CLT_NBR, B2H_STATUS

RETURN
END

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `dbo.ufn_B2H_Enrolled_Clients_List` function has parameters you could convert it to an inline `UDF` thus:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufn_B2H_Enrolled_Clients_List](@From_DT datetime, @To_DT datetime)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS 
RETURN
      SELECT CLT_NBR
      FROM ECMS.dbo.ufn_B2H_STATUSES_THROUGH_DT(@To_DT) s1
      WHERE s1.B2H_STATUS=4 AND s1.Max_Effect_DT <DATEADD(d,1,@To_DT)
            --Exclude all clients disenrolled or transferred out prior to the start date
            EXCEPT
            SELECT s2.CLT_NBR
            FROM ECMS.dbo.ufn_B2H_STATUSES_THROUGH_DT(@To_DT) s2 JOIN ECMS.dbo.ufn_B2H_STATUSES_THROUGH_DT(@To_DT) s1 ON s1.CLT_NBR=s2.CLT_NBR
            WHERE s2.B2H_STATUS IN (7,9) AND s2.Max_Effect_DT <@From_DT AND s2.Max_Effect_DT>s1.Max_Effect_DT AND s1.B2H_STATUS IN (4,8)
                  --Exclude all clients who transferred in after the prior end date.
                  EXCEPT
                  SELECT s3.CLT_NBR
                  FROM ECMS.dbo.B2H_STATUS s3 JOIN ECMS.dbo.ufn_B2H_STATUSES_THROUGH_DT(@To_DT) s1 ON s1.CLT_NBR=s3.CLT_NBR
                  WHERE s3.B2H_STATUS = 8 AND s1.B2H_STATUS IN (4,8) AND s3.EFFECT_DT > @To_DT AND s3.Effect_DT>s1.Max_Effect_DT

GO
```

An inline `UDF` is a view with parameters:

> Inline functions can be used to achieve the functionality of
>   parameterized views.

References: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214762(v=sql.80).aspx